# Counting occurrences of elements without .groupBy

Tags: list, scala, scala-collections

I need to count occurrences of element in list.

List looks like this: `List[(String, String, Int)]` - list of `(String, String, Int)` tuples.

Example:

```
List(("Gregor", "Math", 6), ("Mark", "Math", 33), 
     ("Gregor", "IT", 44),  ("Jane", "Math", 3), 
     ("Mark", "Geography", 44), ("Gregor", "sdf", 32))
```

And I need to return list of pairs (name, occurrences in list)
For this example it should be

```
List(("Gregor", 3), ("Mark", 2), ("Jane", 1))
```

I tried with map and foldLeft but i dont have idea how can I do that

Comment: Take a look at the `groupBy` function?

Comment: I can only use map, foldleft, foldright and filter for this task.

Comment: So this is homework? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with only using `foldLeft`:

```
val t = List(("Gregor", "Math", 6), ("Mark", "Mat", 33), 
    ("Gregor", "IT", 44), ("Jane", "Math", 3), ("Mark", "Geography", 44), 
    ("Gregor", "sdf", 32))

val res = t.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]()) { case(m, (n, _, _)) => 
    m + (n -> (m.getOrElse(n, 0) + 1)) 
}.toList
```

Comment: I guess you have to use the toList right? Atleast otherwise you will have a truly horrible complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
users.groupBy(u => u._1).map(u => (u._1, u._2.length)).toList
```

Comment: `groupBy` can't be used, this was my first thought too.

Comment: Hm. Strange constraint, but ok, I'll give it a thought. 
Any other constraints?

Comment: Check the comments on the question, he did say that we are only allowed to use `foldLeft`, `foldRight`, `map` and `filter`. It's obviously a homework question but fun nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val list = List(("Gregor", "Math", 6), ("Mark", "Mat", 33), ("Gregor", "IT", 44), ("Jane", "Math", 3), ("Mark", "Geography", 44), ("Gregor", "sdf", 32))
list: List[(String, String, Int)] = List((Gregor,Math,6), (Mark,Mat,33), (Gregor,IT,44), (Jane,Math,3), (Mark,Geography,44), (Gregor,sdf,32))

scala> val res = list.groupBy(_._1) map { case (k, xs) => k -> xs.size } toList
res: List[(String, Int)] = List((Gregor,3), (Jane,1), (Mark,2))
```